# How to load a big size image to later use it for a background-image hover effect with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, background-image, css-transitions

I am trying to fade two background images using jQuery and a CSS transition and it works, but the images are high resolution and quite big even though I compressed them as much as I could for web usage but keeping resolution and details. It wouldn't work well with moderately slow internet speeds, because the first time I hover over the trigger element a white screen lapsus which I really don't like.

I know I could do this by adding a hidden div with that background-image url that would be set to display: none; and trigger an opacity change, but I would like to know if there's a better way to do that. Such as loading the image prior to the hover function takes place so when the document is ready. Maybe it could still happen, but much more unlikely.

The CSS transition works well when I hover on the trigger element, but on mouse out the image just disappears without fading, I am not sure if I should approach the issue using jQuery or directly CSS. Anyway, the issue is loading the image before the hover function starts. I will try AJAX load() method...

```
#Introduction {
    background: url(url.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: background 1.5s linear;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#LogoContainer').hover(function() {
    $('#LogoMainPiece').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
    $('#LogoOtherPiece').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $('#Introduction').css('background-image', 'url(hoverurl.jpg)');
}, function() { 
    $('#LogoMainPiece').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    $('#LogoOtherPiece').fadeTo('slow', 0.3);
    $('#Introduction').css('background-image', 'url(url.jpg)');
});
});
```

Comment: did you google 'preloading images'?

Comment: you may use CSS with pseudo and opacity to mimic a fade effect, background-image does not have opacity options. example :  http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/DJdja

Comment: I don't need a loader.. I am trying to achieve a section background hover effect which trigger is the logo container. As for the CSS effect, I do like it, but I would really prefer to use jQuery for this unless I have no option, which I am trying to find out. So far I managed to fade the background-image with jQuery with no problem. The issue is that the first time I hover it the hover background loads for the first time. And I think the CSS  transition doesn't work in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

```
#Introduction {
    background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#IntroductionHoverBackground {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 730px;
    background: url(hoverbg.jpg) no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size: cover;
    display: none;
}

<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#LogoContainer').hover(function() {
        $('#LogoMainPart').fadeTo('slow', 0.37);
        $('#LogoOtherPart').fadeTo('slow', 1);
        $('#IntroductionHoverBackground').fadeTo('slow', 1);
    }, function() { 
        $('#LogoMainPart').fadeTo('slow', 1);
        $('#LogoOtherPart').fadeTo('slow', 0.37);
        $('#IntroductionHoverBackground').fadeTo('slow', 0);
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```